# Density: Game looks the same on every screen-size

Tags: android, dpi, screen-size

i'm having a little trouble with my android app and different screen sizes.
I want my game to look the same on every screen but i uses static px-values to fit it on my phone (HTC one m7, 1080x1920, 468 dpi).

The Code for the Header looks like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(header, null, new Rect(0,0,1080,200), null);
```

Now i want it to fit on every Screen. I read some tutorials for using dp (is that what i want and need?) but none of them worked. Or am i just using the wrong calculations?

Or do i have to work with f.E. 1/7*width and so on...

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Simon, that link is actually useless for what he wants to do, he's using the canvas.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Why is it useless?  I use DPs all the time in custom views in the onMeasure() methods and so on with the required pixel counts stored in class fields.  Once you understand the system, it's easy.

Comment: He's making a game using the Canvas. Drawing on the Canvas is more  intricate than making a custom view. And except for a FrameLayout to contain the Canvas in, the android layout system and most of the best practices that come with it do not really apply in his case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, you can use dp (density independent pixels) or px, but measure everything yourself at run-time.

Since you're obviously not using the built-in layout classes of Android, you really do have to measure everything yourself.

And yes, by that I mean you have to "work with f.E. 1/7*width and so on...". Just do not assume what the width is, determine that width at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `integer.xml` in various values folders, and use the values `(0,0,1080,200)` according to your need. For e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="leftwidth">0</integer>
<integer name="rightwidth">0</integer>
<integer name="topwidth">1080</integer>
<integer name="bottomwidth">200</integer>
</resources>
```

Now you can get these values by calling:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(header, null, new Rect(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.leftwidth),getResources().getInteger(R.integer.rightwidth),getResources().getInteger(R.integer.topwidth),getResources().getInteger(R.integer.bottomwidth)), null);
```

Comment: Why not? I have just shown him another approach for solving his prob. @StephanBranczyk

Comment: Hardcoding values for his specific phone won't work with phone screens of other dimensions. Furthermore, the value for the height can change depending on the status bar and the main navigation buttons.